# Is it better to subscribe inside a subscription or use rxjs concat with tap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I reserve data in the backend, then I get all reserved data for that item.
Getting the data must only occur after the reservation so that it will be included.

I have two solutions, but wonder which is the best one and if there is any advantage of using concat with tap in this example:

**subscription inside subscription:**

```
...
this.reserveDataItem();
...

reserveDataItem(){
   this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData).subscribe(res => {
     if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
       ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff
     }
     this.getReservedDataItemsId();
   });
 }


getReservedDataItemsId(){
   this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId).subscribe(res => {
     if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
       ..doStuffWithDataItems
     }
   });
 }
```

**concat with tap:**
*I used tap because I couldn't find how to handle different return types in a single subscription

and thus I'm wondering if there is any advantage here..*

```
...
concat(this.reserveDataItem(), this.getReservedDataItemsId())
   .subscribe();
...

reserveDataItem(): Observable<ApiResponseDto<any>>{
  return this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
        ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff
      }
    })
  )
 }


getReservedDataItemsId():Observable<ApiResponseDto<DataItemDto[]>>{
   return this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId).pipe(
    tap(res => {
       if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
         ..doStuffWithDataItems
       }
     })
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question and problem:

You are writing some data on the back-end (first Observable) and after the data is written/saved, you will get a response (complete the first Observable). The response status from the first requirement doesn't have to be 'success', you want to make another request no matter what resp you get. Only after the first Observable completes, you want to make another request to get this data.

Assuming your `reserveData` method makes one Http request,
I would use `switchMap`:

`"For instance, when using switchMap each inner subscription is completed when the source emits, allowing only one active inner subscription."`
(from the https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

Here is my simplified code, how I would solve the issue:

```
myObs = new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next({status: 'SUCCESS'});
    observer.complete();
});

myObs2 = new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next({status: 'SUCCESS'});
    observer.complete();
});

this.myObs.pipe(
  switchMap((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 'SUCCESS') ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff;
    return this.myObs2;
  })
).subscribe(resp => {
  if (resp.status === 'SUCCESS') ...doStuffWithDataItems;
})
```

Here is my question, which is kind of related to your issue. An Http request/response produces 'only the last notification (the result from the HTTP request) is returned as seen' so in my opinion you don't need to use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` (again, assuming your `reserveData` method basically makes one Http request and returns a response).

Comment: Indeed the premise of the problem is correct. Both subscriptions simple do a http call. Thank you for your solution, but again the question is.. is there any advantage in this use case of using a rxjs solution instead of an inner subscription?

Comment: oh ok.. So, in my opinion, it is a lot of a matter of a clean, readable and modern code. I don't really know if using rxjs switchMap is faster or not, but surely by  using it, you are showing that you know what you're doing/what you are trying to archieve and the code is easily scanable and understandable.

Comment: As your question is about only sequential observables, the most difference in my opinion is style, but if you asked about different methods as `mergeMap` vs Promises, here you can read a good article about advantages of RxJS. https://medium.com/@ravishivt/batch-processing-with-rxjs-6408b0761f39 . I think, summary of the article is a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use forkJoin instead :

```
    const result1 = this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData);
    const result2 = this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId);
    
    getData(): Observable<any> {
      return forkJoin([result1, result2]);
    }
    
    this.getData().subscribe(res => {
       //...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff res[0]
       //..doStuffWithDataItems res[1]
    }, err => {
       console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Ok, but forkJoin does not ensure (to my knowledge) that the first observable will have completed before the second is called.. so this is not a good solution

Comment: forkJoin emit the last emitted value from result when all observables complete, then If an inner observable does not complete forkJoin will never emit a value!

Comment: Yes... but if getReservedDataItemsId completes first, it will not hold the newly reserved data which hasn't completed his reservation on the backend with function reserveDataItem.. right?
This means that the value which will be emitted will not be correct for the use case mentionned in the question.

Comment: Ah okey, i think that i don't understand your request at the first time so you will use another RxJs operator like (mergeMap or switchMap)

Answer (score 0):

This should mimik your code without nesting subscriptions:

```
this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData).pipe(
  mergeMap(res => {
    if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
      ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff
    }
    return this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId)
  })
).subscribe(res => {
  if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
    ..doStuffWithDataItems
  }
});
```

Without knowing more about what it is you're doing here, it's hard to give advice about which one is better. The above code allows you to expand your data pipeline with additional transformations (via map) or filters without much hassle. This way you're not going to keep nesting more and more subscriptions.

For example, you can filter out failures since you just ignore them at the moment, then this is again equivalent to the code above.

```
this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData).pipe(
  mergeMap(res => {
    if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
      ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff
    }
    return this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId)
  }),
  filter(res => res.status == 'SUCCESS')
).subscribe(res => {
  // Now we already *know* that res.status is 'SUCCESS' here
  // No need to check
  ..doStuffWithDataItems
});
```

What if I want my data from the backend in a specific format or I only want a subset. Lets pretend the result to return a user with first name, last name, and current age. I want the first name to be regular (first letter uppercase, the rest lowercase) and the last name to be all caps. I also need to calculate the birthday from the year.

```
this.myService.reserveData(this.selectedData).pipe(
  mergeMap(res => {
    if (res.status == 'SUCCESS'){
      ...logSuccessMessagesAndOtherStuff
    }
    return this.myService.getReservedDataItemsForRequestId(this.requestId)
  }),
  filter(res => res.status == 'SUCCESS'),
  map(res => ({
    firstName: res.userdata.fname[0].toUpperCase() + res.userdata.fname.toLowerCase().slice(1),
    lastName: res.userdata.lname.toUpperCase(),
    age: (2020 - res.userdata.birthyear)
  }))
).subscribe(user => {
  ..doStuffWithUser
});
```